# search data with not accented word to find accented words in Node and mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, nosql

I work on a translator MERN stack app I have in the database the word föderativ, and the user can only search for this word by using this accented ö letter but I want that user can simply type a foderativ and then that can match this föderativ word, I want that some non accented word can match accented words. I have some solution but I don't know what to do with this :

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/analyzers/token-filters/#std-label-asciiFolding-tf-ref

But where do I need to put this code, is this some settings or what? How to use these tokens I really don't know. If you have any other solutions please help

```
{
     "analyzer": "asciiConverter",
     "searchAnalyzer": "asciiConverter",
     "mappings": {
       "dynamic": true
     },
     "analyzers": [
       {
         "name": "asciiConverter",
         "tokenizer": {
           "type": "standard"
         },
         "tokenFilters": [
           {
             "type": "asciiFolding"
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
```

This is how i get search query with nodeJs

```
exports.search = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const query = [
      {
        $match: {},
      },
      {
        $project: {},
      },
      {
        $limit: 10,
      },
    ];

    const projection = {
      'bosnian.value': 1,
      'german.value': 1,
      'english.value': 1,
    };

    var reqProjections = {};
    req.query.projections
      ? (reqProjections = JSON.parse(req.query.projections))
      : null;

    query[0].$match[
      `${req.query.category || 'word'}.${req.query.lan || 'bosnian'}.value`
    ] = {
      $regex: req.query.word || '',
      $options: 'i',
    };

    req.query.limit ? (query[2].$limit = parseInt(req.query.limit)) : null;

    reqProjections.length
      ? reqProjections.map(
          (proj) => (query[1].$project[`${proj}`] = projection)
        )
      : (query[1].$project[`${req.query.category || 'word'}`] = projection);

    const data = await aggregate(model, query);

    responseHandler(data, res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    errorHandler(500, res, err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/create-index/#create-an-fts-index-using-the-service-ui

Answer (score 0):

This is touching on the big topic of [collation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/collation-locales-defaults/#std-label-collation-languages-locales) and the details of the solution will depend on how you're querying your database exactly.

But for example if you have a document which has a field: `str: "föderativ"` then this query will return it, using weak German collation options:

```
db.collection.find(
  { str: 'foderativ' }
   null,
  { collation: { locale: 'de', strength: 1 }  }
)
```

For this query to be able to use an index on `str`, the index should also be built with the same custom collation.

If you're doing full text search, I believe it should ignore umlaut without any additional configuration, but if not, you can also create full text indexes with custom collation.

Comment: I create custom indexes and I put the token in atlas search index configuration, and when  I test the words in atlas search tester now it works,  but my setup is different

Comment: I added the nodeJs code up in the question section